# Joining sql server table data & postgresql table data

Tags: querying

We have a table in Sql server database and another table in postgresql database with some common columns in both the tables. and we want to compare these tables data using the common columns in join condition? what is the best solution to do this? and what are all the possible solutions for this. please help me in it.

I have imported bulk data from postgresql to sql server using bcp utility. and compared data. but we are looking to not import and join directly. please provide best solutions for this.